# VTK Question - RGB for skin

Tags: graphics, vtk

What should be the RGB colour composition of the skin surface scaled between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calibrate your decision surface for false positives and false negatives, from lighting conditions, camera setup, etc. There won't exist one value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of skin you want to have. There are a lot of skin types in the world. A first google "white skin" hit says its around: RGB(239,208,207). Or scaled: nRGB(0.94,0.82,0.81).

But it also depends on what medium is used to visualize it. You can probably google on some models for skin color which tell you that regular RGB color model is not the way to go. Or methods how to alter the value in order to look great on your screen / prints / whatever.